# SetFoucsOnError in mVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to set focus on the control while error occurs. I am use mvc 2.0. In Asp.net we have a property **SetFoucsOnError** but in MVC what is the substitute of it and how to implement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I did not get this solution. But i got an alternate option which even works :

```
$().ready(function() {

        $("#Form").submit(function() {
            $('.input-validation-error').focus();
            $(".input-validation-error").each(function() {
                $(this).focus();
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use JavaScript.

The example uses jQuery and assumes controls with invalid data have a css class called `input-validation-error`:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $(this).find('input.input-validation-error, select.input-validation-error')
               .first()
               .focus();
    });
});
```

This will look for all input and select elements with the class `input-validation-error`, take the first of them and put the focus on it.

Comment: Almost same thing that i do in my post